# The equals() method in Java works unexpectedly on Long data type

Tags: java

Let's first consider the following expressions in Java.

```
Integer temp = new Integer(1);
System.out.println(temp.equals(1));

if(temp.equals(1))
{
     System.out.println("The if block executed.");
}
```

These all statements work just fine. There is no question about it. The expression `temp.equals(1)` is evaluated to `true` as expected and the only statement within the `if` block is executed consequently.

---

Now, when I change the data type from `Integer` to `Long`, the statement `temp1.equals(1)` is unexpectedly evaluated to `false` as follows.

```
Long temp1 = new Long(1);
System.out.println(temp1.equals(1));

if(temp1.equals(1))
{
    System.out.println("The if block executed.");
}
```

These are the equivalent statements to those mentioned in the preceding snippet just the data type has been changed and they behave exactly opposite.

The expression `temp1.equals(1)` is evaluated to `false` and consequently, the only statement within the `if` block is not executed which the reverse of the preceding statements. How?

Comment: Documentation says that `.equals` returns true only if both objects are of type `long`.

Comment: I tried `if(temp1.longValue()==1)` and `if(temp1.equals(1l)` both worked as expected.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You're comparing a `Long` to an `int`.  The javadoc for [`java.lang.Long#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) says that the `equals` method

> Compares this object to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a Long object that contains the same long value as this object.

Instead try `System.out.println(new Long(1).equals(1L));`  Now that you're comparing a `Long` to a `Long` instead of a `Long` to an `Integer`, it will print `true`.

Comment: @TheLQ Are you asking whether you can do `new Long(1L)`?  Yes, you can.  `1L` basically represents a `long` type.  Since the `Long` constructor accepts `long`s, it will accept `1L` as the constructor argument.

Comment: @JackEdmonds there is no need for `new Long(...)` here though, `1L` would suffice

Comment: @Eugene `1L` is a unboxed primitive, you cannot do `1L.equals(1L)`.  You definitely need to have a `Long` object in order to use its `equals()` method.

Comment: Ah, so you're suggesting the single statement be rewritten as two.  Sure, yes that can be done.  But there's "no need".

Answer (score 8):

The reason you can do that comparison is because of autoboxing in Java.

The actual method you are calling is this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

which is comparing your Long object to some other Object, not to an actual primitive int.

What happens when you call the method is that your primitive `integer(1)` is being autoboxed into an `Object(Integer)` so then you are effectively calling:

```
new Long(1).equals(new Integer(1));
```

which is why it fails.

This is why if you call

```
new Long(1).equals(1L)
```

this would work, because Java will autobox the `1L` (primitive `long`, not `int`) into a `Long` object, not an `Integer` object.

Answer (score 7):

The literal value `1` is *not* a `long`, it's an `int`. Try the above code with this instead:

```
System.out.println(temp1.equals(1L));
```

And

```
if (temp1.equals(1L))
```

As you can see, putting an `L` after the literal value `1` indicates that it's a `long`, and then the comparisons work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Java is being lazy.

When you perform the following comparison java will automatically cast the int to a long (as a long can contain any value an int can contain). And the comparison is between two longs and not two ints.

```
int i = 1;
long l = 1L;
boolean b = i == l;
```

Java is able to do this because the type information about `i` and `l` is known at compile time **and** when performing the comparison. However, when you use the boxed version the type can be known at compile time, but **not** when performing the comparison. This is because the comparison has to done within an equals method, and since equals takes Object as a parameter the type information is lost. Thus Java is lazy and only checks to see if two boxed numbers are equal if they are both of instances of same Number class (eg. both Integer, or both Long, or both Double, etc...).

Turns out the only fully reliable way to compare two numbers of unknown type at runtime is to convert both to strings and both to BigDecimal and then to use the method compareTo (and **not** equals). Though if you know you are only ever going to get longs and ints then life is simpler as you can just do the following.

```
Number n0 = new Long(1L);
Number n1 = new Integer(1);
boolean equal = n0.longValue() == n1.longValue();
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could add an example and the official source for the mentioned "fully reliable way" to compare the value of two Numbers of unknown type. Thanks and upvote anyway!

Comment: Can anyone explain more about "However, when you use the boxed version the type can be known at compile time, but not when performing the comparison."? I doubt that this would be in the other way because of polymorphism. Thanks a lot if you can help me!

Answer (score 3):

According to [Javadoc's page on `Long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html), the [`.equals` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) evaluates to `true` only if

1. The argument is a `Long` object
2. If (1) is true, then the `Long` objects must have equal values

In your scenario, `1` is an `int`, not a `Long` object, so it fails (1), and therefore, evaluates to false. If you need to test to a `long`, use `1L` instead.

Answer (score 2):

That behaviour is consistent with autoboxing converting the `1` to an `Integer` which then compares equal to another `Integer(1)`. Comparing a `Long` to an `Integer` yields `false`.

If you would use `1L` to compare against `Long` it would yield `true`.

Answer (score 2):

> Long temp1 = new Long(1); System.out.println(temp1.equals(1));
>
> if(temp1.equals(1)) {
>       System.out.println("The if block executed."); }

in this code `temp1.equals(1)` is comparing a `Long` object to `Integer` object which gives the result false ,we can correct it by using `1L` instead of `1` ,,,eg `temp1.equals(1L)`, by doing this we are comparing `Long` object with a `Long` and gives result TRUE

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method of class [Long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) illustrates why:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Long) {
        return value == ((Long)obj).longValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The equals method in Java.lang.Long initially starts with an instanceOf Long check only after that the value is compared.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
     if (obj instanceof Long) {
         return value == ((Long)obj).longValue();
     }         
     return false;
}
```

So if you are going to use and Integer Value int the place of a Long value then the first check fails and hence you will get false as the result .

Answer (score 0):

You can compare Long/integer values without uting equals(). This is only needed when you are comparing strings as far as I know.