# Cannot invoke equals(long) on the primitive type long

Tags: java, android, equals, equals-operator

I couldnt use `equals` with long values:

```
    long a = 20; //or 20L
    long b = 20; //or 20L
    if(a.equals(b)) {
        //do
    }
```

> error: Cannot invoke equals(long) on the primitive type long

Also `==` does not work with long values.

How can I check if long values equals?

Comment: if(l1 == 2) try this way

Comment: You can check == for primitive datas.

Comment: why do you think `==` does not work comparing long values?

Comment: It's not really a problem you can't find on `SO` or google. Please search before asking these kind of questions http://stackoverflow.com/a/8671419/1141395

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`==` does work with long values.

Answer (score 4):

`==` operator used to compare `primitive` value and `equals()` method used to compare `Object`

Since, `long` is a primitive type then you have to use `==` operator for primitive type data as below...

```
if(a == b ) {
    //do
}
```

The `equals()` is used to compare 2 `Object` and `Long` is an `Object` type of `long`. If you declare your instances as `Long` type then you can use `equals()` method as below...

```
Long a = 20;
Long b = 20;

if(a.equals(b)) {
    //do
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For [primitive data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) you should use `==`.

And for [objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type) you should use the `equals` function.

In your case it would be:

```
long a = 20; //or 20L
long b = 20; //or 20L
if(a == b) {
    //do
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`==` works for `long`, if you want to use `equals`:

```
Long a = new Long(20);
Long b = new Long(20);
if(a.equals(b))
```